# Problem with permute and lattice while installing vegan package

Tags: installation, lattice, vegan, permute

I'm trying to do my homework, but got somehow stuck. Please help!
[image: Screenshot]

I've already installed "permute" and "lattice" ... but it still doesn't work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no indication of an error there; R is telling you that the packages were loaded correctly and that *vegan* also loaded correctly.